# MSBuild: imported project ... Sdk.props was not found

Tags: c#, msbuild

I installed Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 and tried to build the [DiscUtils solution](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils) with:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" DiscUtils.sln
```

I get for all 51 C# projects:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not found.
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Comment: Erm, wait, where did you get this from?  There was a "Build tools for VS2017" in the RC release but it was only meant for C++ builds and they decided to not include it in the RTM release.  Google is stumped as well.  So by and large, failure is the expected outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant: I used:
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ -> Other Tools and Frameworks -> Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017.  
I chose Individual Components -> C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers. 
Probably these are not the proper compilers, are they?

Comment: Looks legit.  Probably not, do note how it noodles about C++.  But certainly odd that it offers Roslyn.  Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem is your best bet.

Comment: there is a separate package / workload for C++ projects. The "normal" build tools are just broken at the moment for sdk-based projects..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short MSBuild is broken, see @Martin Ullrich.

To build use:

```
choco install dotnetcore-sdk
& "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"  restore  DiscUtils.sln
& "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" msbuild DiscUtils.sln -p:FrameworkPathOverride="c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"
```

If you don't use Chocolatey, download manually the [.NET Core SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847097)

`FrameworkPathOverride` is necessary if you don't have Visual Studio. VS solutions expects to find reference assemblies in:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v*
```

Without VS, you can resort to those in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

Note that, if the solutions generates different assembly for different targets frameworks and you need them, you need to install related SDKs.

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing, the VS 2017 Build Tools are missing critical components necessary for building SDK-based ("new-world") csproj files (to be specific: the SDKs and integrated NuGet are missing).

See this GitHub issue for tracking and a few workarounds: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1697